# Javafx Table row border causes shifting on elements within

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add a red border to selected table rows and the elements in the row are shifting.

This is my css:

```
.my-table .table-row-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-border-color: red;
}
```

This is a screenshot of how it looks like.

[image]

How can I rectify this?
I've tried changing the border insets but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1 ;
```

The code for creating the table is:

```
<TableView styleClass="my-table" editable="false" >
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnNumber" minWidth="70" prefWidth="70" sortable="false" text="Solution" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnOne" minWidth="0" prefWidth="40" sortable="false" text="columnOne" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnTwo" minWidth="40" prefWidth="40" sortable="false" text="columnTwo" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnThree" minWidth="70" prefWidth="70" sortable="false" text="columnThree" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnFour" minWidth="40" prefWidth="40" sortable="false" text="columnFour" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnFive" minWidth="80" prefWidth="80" sortable="false" text="columnFive" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnSix" minWidth="80" prefWidth="80" sortable="false" text="columnSix" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnSeven" minWidth="80" prefWidth="80" sortable="false" text="columnSeven" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnEight" minWidth="180" prefWidth="180" sortable="false" text="columnEight" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="action" minWidth="100" prefWidth="100" sortable="false" text="" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

The styles applied are:

```
.table-view {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the code that creates the table? Please also provide the code that populates the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hers is a dirty fix:

```
 .my-table .table-row-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 -1 0 -1;
}
```

Or

```
.my-table .table-row-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-padding: -1;
}
```